# series inequality

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show $|\frac{1}{1+x^{2}} -(1- x^{2} +x^{4} - ...+ (-1)^{n}x^{2n}| \leq x^{2n+2}$ for any positive integer $n$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$? I thought about using the triangle inequality but I don't think it made the problem simpler.

Comment: Consider the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: How would I apply it to this situation? @saulspatz

Comment: The left-hand side is the remainder after taking $2^n$ terms.  Write out the remainder as an infinite series, and see what that suggests.

Comment: @ajaaaaaa It is very unfair to drastically modify a question after answers are provided. I got downvoted because of this. **Please of not do this in future**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\begin{align}\mathrm{LHS}&=\left|\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}-[1-x^2+\ldots+(-1)^nx^{2n}]\right|
\\
&=\left|\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}-\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-x^2)^{i}\right|
\\
&=\left|\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}-\frac{\left(-x^{2}\right)^{n+1}-1}{-x^{2}-1}\right|
\end{align}$$

You should be able to compare it to the RHS from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity
$$(1+u)(1-u+u^2-\dots +(-1)^nx^n)=1+(-1)^nx^{n+1},$$
whence
$$\frac1{1+u}=1-u+u^2-\dots +(-1)^nx^n+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}u^{n+1}}{1+u},$$
then set $u=x^2$ and use that
$$\frac{u^{n+1}}{1+u}=\frac{x^{2n+2}}{1+x^2}<x^{2n+2}.$$